# Calculating top 5 users with the most points in the current category or category below it

Tags: php, mysql

I have a points system on my website and points are gained for different achievements within the different website categories. Categories can have sub-categories and parent categories using the 'category_relations' table with 'links_to' and 'links_from' fields holding the relevant category_id's.

What i'd like to do is fetch the top 5 users with the most points in the current category and any categories directly below it.

My 'points_awarded' table has all the records of any points awarded and to what users from what categories:

user_id,
points_amount,
plus (tinyint boolean if it's points added or not),
minus (tinyint boolean if it's point penalty or not),
category_id

I don't really know where to start with this. Will i need to have two queries, one to fetch all sub category id's, and then one to use that to run another query to fetch SUM() of the points used? Is it possible to do it in one query?

Comment: Show me Your code which You are trying ....

Comment: Are you John Williams the famous composer or a different one?

Comment: Are you the father of the awesome Joseph Williams AS WELL !? MY GOD THAT'S AWESOME MAN I AM SO GLAD YOU'RE PROGRAMMING NOW ! WEB 3.0 IS ON ITS WAY !!!!!!!!!!! CANNOT BELIEVE IT ><

Comment: I still can't believe it. Honestly.

Comment: Oh, I see. I will try that :) I hope I'll meet you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd need more information about your database tables to be sure but something like this will probably work:

```
SELECT 
    `user_id`, 
    SUM(IF(`plus`, `points_amount`, 0)) - SUM(IF(`minus`, `points_amount`, 0)) AS `points`
FROM 
    `points_awarded`
WHERE
    `user_id` = $user_id
    AND (
        `category_id` = $cat_id
        OR `category_id` IN(
            SELECT `links_to`
            FROM `category_relations`
            WHERE `links_from` = $cat_id
        )
    )
GROUP BY `user_id`
```

I'm curious though, why do you have a plus field and a minus field? If plus is false, can't we assume it's minus? Why have either field anyway, why not just make points_amount a signed field?

Comment: thanks, i'll give that a go now. I noticed as i was typing that i didn't need both fields so that will be changed. The reason for both fields and not having just a 'points_amount' is that i want to show users their previous plus and minus points records. So rather than having plus/minus and points amount, i'll just run a query to calculate this as and when i need...always up for better suggestions though. :)

Comment: Supposing you only have one signed field for points and no plus or minus fields at all, you might do a query like: `SELECT SUM(IF(points_amount > 0, points_amount, 0)) AS points_awarded, SUM(IF(points_amount < 0, points_amount, 0)) AS points_subtracted` this would get you the same information with a simpler table structure.